# How do I make an animation pause and resume?

Tags: java, animation, pause

I am not speaking with a bottom feature. Just an animation that runs to point X stops for certain amount of time and resumes. The reason I ask this is because I have to animate a program where a UFO flies over buildings, stops over a building, makes it disappear with a beam, and moves on. Here is what I have:

```java
import java.awt.Color;

import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class UFO extends GraphicsProgram {
    public static final int APP_W = 800;
    public static final int APP_H = 600;

    public void init() {
        setSize(APP_W, APP_H);
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    public void run() {
        GBuilding Tower = new GBuilding(10, 400, Color.black, 80);
        add(Tower);

        GBuilding Tower2 = new GBuilding(160, 400, Color.CYAN, 80);
        add(Tower2);

        GBuilding Tower3 = new GBuilding(260, 400, Color.RED, 80);
        add(Tower3);

        GBuilding Tower4 = new GBuilding(410, 400, Color.BLUE, 80);
        add(Tower4);

        GBuilding Tower5 = new GBuilding(490, 400, Color.WHITE, 80);
        add(Tower5);

        GBuilding Tower6 = new GBuilding(640, 400, Color.GREEN, 80);
        add(Tower6);

        UFOmodel ufo = new UFOmodel(Color.GREEN, 0, 250);
        add(ufo);

        while (true) {
            ufo.move(10, 0);
            pause(30);

        }

    }
}
```

Obviously this is a GCompound with the building in a separate class and the UFO in a separate class. Basically, I have no idea how to make the UFO move to point X, then at that time at that point have a beam flash while using

```
getElementAt(20,20).setVisible(false);
```

at that time to make the building disappear and then have the animation continue with the ufo leaving screen.

Comment: Is there some way to get the current x and y from a GraphicsProgram? If so, after a move, check the x and y to see if the UFO's in the right place and if so, perform the other functions. Even if GraphicsProgram doesn't make available the current x and y coordinates, you can keep track of them in the UFO class and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize the job of making an animation like constructing and displaying frames of a movie film. Draw a frame, pause for a frame interval to display it, update the frame, pause, update, ...

Now plan out the drawing steps for those frames. First there's a sequence of frames where the UFO moves, then maybe a few frames where it just hovers, then show the laser beam for a frame or two, then hide the laser beam and the target building and just hover for a frame or two, then a sequence where the UFO moves on.

So far, you have a `while` loop that implements the moving UFO. You need to expand that to implement the larger plan -- the 5 sequences above. Each of those 5 sequences will change some graphics objects and loop for a suitable number of frames.

Just hovering can be done by looping the desired number of frames, maybe nudging the UFO's position a little back and forth.

Moving the UFO to the firing position can be done by looping the right number of frames until the cumulative motion spans the desired distance. Although you could precompute that distance, it's easier and more adaptable (e.g. adapts to different window sizes) if it loops until the UFO's position is right. E.g. `while (ufo.getX() < building.getX())`.

(The `object.getX()` call assumes you're using this [Stanford graphics package](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/graphics/package-summary.html).)

Implement the first sequence and debug it. Then add the second sequence following it in the code, and debug that. Then add the next sequence, and so on.

Use an IDE and debugger, such as IntelliJ Idea. It will help greatly, e.g. it can single-step through the program so so can see what each step actually does, which might not match your expectation.